# How can I access data through API URL using custom token authorization in laravel

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, postman, laravel-middleware

I have created a custom function in middleware which return the data after header token validation. It works fine and I can access the data using postman (Please check the attached screenshot below taken from postman). This is the code in middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $token = $request->header('APP_KEY');
    if ($token != 'XXXX') {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'API Key not found!'], 401);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

The problem I am facing now, I can not get the data from browser URL. I have tried http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/?APP_KEY=XXXX

[image: Access Data Using Postman]

Comment: I think that `APP_KEY` in the code and URL you posted would be available via `$request->input('APP_KEY')`, as it is a query string parameter (following the `?` in the URL). I'm not actually familiar with the `$request->header()` method, so I can't say how you'd access it via that.

Comment: It works like magic. Thank you.  Sorry I am not expert in laravel.

Comment: No problem! I'm not sure if that's "correct" (having the key in the URL like that, but maybe someone else knows). Happy to help either way :)

Comment: Whatever It solved the issue and saved me. Stack-overflow rocks. Thanks :)